# Универсальность употребления слов "пол" и "потолок"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли по отношению к лифту, автобусу, поезду, самолёту употреблять слова "пол" и "потолок"?

Answer (score 1):

**Пол** есть даже у землянки, как и у *любого крытого помещения, предназначенного для пребывания людей*. *Сомнения* относительно *пола* или *потолка* возможны в случаях:

- когда *потолок не плоский* (*чум, мансарда/чердак*) или *не твёрдый*
  (*навес* над кузовом грузовика, *шатёр* и пр.);
- когда действует профессиональная *терминология*: **палуба** - "пол" любого
  помещения *на корабле*. Однако непосвящённым пассажиром палуба каюты
  воспринимается как "*пол*";
- если помещение *не предназначено для пребывания людей*,  которые
  могут в нём находиться: например, у транспортного контейнера не пол,
  а "**дно**".

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя.

Люди так не говорят, и во всех словарях сказано лишь о помещении:
*Потолок* - верхняя часть, внутреннее покрытие жилого помещения.
*Пол* - нижнее покрытие, настил в помещении, в доме.

Но можно, если написать эти слова в кавычках.

Comment: А какими словами заменить?

Answer (score 0):

Я не думаю, что у носителя языка, который знает, что такое поезд и что такое потолок, может возникнуть вопрос о наличии потолка у поезда. Возможно, вы хотели спросить о купе в поезде, салоне самолёта или автобуса и т.п.? Тогда да: во всех этих случаях речь может идти о полах или потолках, поскольку и *купе*, и *салон* являются помещениями.

В случае лифта всё чуть иначе: *пол лифта* и *потолок лифта* — распространённые выражения (в том числе в добротной литературе), хотя, казалось бы, логичнее было бы и здесь говорить о кабине лифта.

Comment: То есть "Пол в салоне автобуса" — допустимо?

Comment: @Владимир Конечно. Похоже, что и "потолок автобуса" вполне допустимо и часто встречается (без салона). Вероятно, автобус и лифт однозначно ассоциируются со своими салоном и кабиной, соответственно. "Пол салона автобуса" встречается реже, может, потому что звучит не очень удачно (как половина).